# "Facebook Likes" on my website are lost

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I added "Facebook like button" into each topic of my forum (vBulletin).

Something like "198,286 people like this. Be the first of your friends."

But one day, **some** topic lost all it's facebook likes.

And now it has returned to  "Be the first of your friends to like this."

All likes of that topic are lost?

Why is that? and how to fix it?

I'm from Vietnam.

I'm running a contest on my forum, and "Facebook likes" will be the score of each topic.

I found this code on my webpage

```
<!-- Facebook Like --> 
    <div class="fb-like" 
     data-href="MYWEBSITE/forum/showthread.php?t=26367"; 
     data-send="true" data-layout="standard" data-width="375" 
     data-show-faces="false" data-action="like" 
     style="float: right; width: 375px;"></div> 
<!-- /Facebook Like -->
```

End then my website will get the data from FB in a frame –

Comment: You could check if in those threads someone managed to inject <fb:admin> tags to get control over the likes and delete them.

Comment: You didn't change the URL of any of the threads did you?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your website and click view source ,then find anything like facebook

Comment: <!-- Facebook Like -->
    
      
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://MYWEBSITE/forum/showthread.php?t=26367" data-send="true" data-layout="standard" data-width="375" data-show-faces="false" data-action="like"  style="float: right; width: 375px;"></div>
      
      
    
  <!-- /Facebook Like -->
End then my website will get the data from FB in a frame